# Objectify SimpleQuery.endAt() - where exactly does it start from?

Tags: objectify

What is the exact semantics of Objectify's SimpleQuery.endAt()? The documentation says it "ends query results at the specified Cursor" (https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/objectify/cmd/SimpleQuery.java?r=a7402d1a9308fbb7b9fd6cb687e43be091d1bcb0#73), which could be interpreted in two ways.

Say the cursor is pointing at result C and I set the query limit to X. Will endAt() return the results in the range [C-X, C], or [0, min(X,C)]? That is, does it start at X results from the cursor and always finish at the cursor, or does it always start from the beginning?

EDIT:
The documentation made me think it would be the former, but what I observed in practice is the latter behaviour. That means that to properly implement pagination for search results, one must keep track of all the cursors and not just the two most recent ones. This is fine, but I think the documentation should be a bit more explicit about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objectify's `endAt()` just passes the cursor to the low level API's `FetchOptions.endCursor()`; `limit()` just passes the value to `FetchOptions.limit()`. The interaction is defined by Google and does not appear to be documented. The most relevant bits I can find are:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/FetchOptions#endCursor(com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Cursor)

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Java_Query_cursors

I would ask on the appengine google group, or maybe repost another stackoverflow question generalizing the question to GAE (drop the Objectify and Java-specific nature). With luck there's somebody who knows - possibly in the GAE/Python community, which is somewhat larger than the GAE/Java community.